# Sitecore instance upgradation from 6.6 to 7.2

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, license-key

I just want to get confirm that will i require another license.xml to upgrade my client sitecore instance from 6.6 to 7.2.
My understanding is sitecore version upgradation do not require any license update.
And, i think license is vendor based which depends upon number of installations and not sitecore version based.
Just want to confirm my self with community experts.

Comment: Your existing license is valid, you don't need a new one. But this is a really bad question for SO. I recommend you delete the question and next time ask non-programming Sitecore related questions on [SDN Forums](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum.aspx)

Comment: But stack overflow is community of experts where we can have our quick query resolve, there is nothing like programming and non programming, if you get stuck in devlopment phase than you just requires information and for this only information technology made for.

Thanks for advice but i am not going to delete this, its maybe help many newcomers with gist of asking question, as ours corporate seniors always suggest that never hesitate to ask. No offence.. thanks.

Comment: Actually, SO is all about specific programming problems. Suggest you read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and since you are new you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Or find the correct [exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites) for you needs.

Answer (score 1):

In most scenarios, licenses will apply across 6.6 to 7.2 (or further). However, the only sure way to know is to follow up with your Sitecore sales rep to have them check to see if there are any limits on your license that would prevent you from upgrading to 7.

Comment: Thanks Jay, i was having idea of this but right now i joined a company as a sitecore fresher and sitecore project is very new to this company and we want to upgrade our client from 6.6 to 7.5 .

So, thanks to you for advice.

Comment: If this is your scenario, then it will be your client's sales rep you'll need to contact to validate that their license will support being upgraded.
In almost all scenarios, it should be able to happen.